# DB2 multiple SQL update statements

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update

I am not very experienced with SQL outside of the basics. I'm identifying places in our code that need refactoring and I am trying to optimize some code to limit the number of calls to the DB. I've found some SQL updates that are all updating the same table and am curious how I could go about this...

Here are the update statements:

Host Variables:

```
[u.contentTitle, u.contentDescription, "title and dscr update", u.urlId, u.statusCode, u.urlId, u.statusCode]

[u.contentTitle, u.contentDescription, "title and dscr update", u.urlId, u.statusCode, u.urlId, u.statusCode]

[null, null, 'title and dscr update', u.urlId, u.statusCode]
```

```
UPDATE URL 
SET CONTENT_TITLE = ?, 
    CONTENT_DSCR = ?, 
    SYSTEM_UPDATE_REASON = ?, 
    UPDATED_ON = SYSDATE 
WHERE ID = ? 
  AND CONTENT_TITLE IS NULL 
  AND ? NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 599 OR ID = ? 
  AND CONTENT_TITLE = '' 
  AND ? NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 599

UPDATE URL 
SET CONTENT_TITLE = ?, 
    CONTENT_DSCR = ?, 
    SYSTEM_UPDATE_REASON = ?, 
    UPDATED_ON = SYSDATE 
WHERE ID = ? 
  AND CONTENT_DSCR IS NULL 
  AND ? NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 599 OR ID = ? 
  AND CONTENT_DSCR = '' 
  AND ? NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 599


UPDATE URL 
SET CONTENT_TITLE = ?, 
    CONTENT_DSCR = ?, 
    SYSTEM_UPDATE_REASON = ?, 
    UPDATED_ON = SYSDATE 
WHERE ID = ? 
  AND CONTENT_TITLE IS NOT NULL 
  AND ? BETWEEN 400 AND 599
```

All 3 statements are called during our scraping process... so you can imagine it's triple the calls which is not something we want. Can this be done in one single update?

Comment: `AND ? BETWEEN 400 AND 599` ... you can't bind database column names to `?` placeholders in a prepared statement.  None of your update queries will even run.

Comment: The placeholders are not column names, they are values from the scrape data. These are running right now... just separate calls.

Comment: You need to know whether the host variables provided for the two `ID = ?` conditions in the first two queries have the same value (are the same), and you probably need to know whether the host variables provided for the two `? NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 599` have the same value.  And for the separate statements, are the same values provided for the host variables in the SET clause?  There is a lot of information missing.  If the various sets of variables are the same, then you can combine the queries; if they are not, you can't.  And looking at the SQL shown cannot tell you about the host variables.

Comment: Updated to include host variables